# mysql showing two select statements as one output

Tags: mysql, join, union

Hobby databasist here.

In my database, the statement below will output the number of posts per hour which discussed subject foo.

```
select 
    count(postid) 
from 
    myTable 
where 
    (sub like ("%foo%") or comment like ("%foo%")) 
    and replies != 'NULL'  
group by 
    time div 3600 
order by time div 3600 asc;
```

Output: [time div 3600, foo count]

this statement below would output the number of posts per hour which discussed subject bar.

```
select 
    count(postid) 
from 
    myTable 
where 
    (sub like ("%bar%") or comment like ("%bar%")) 
    and replies != 'NULL'  
group 
    by time div 3600 
order by 
    time div 3600 asc;
```

Output: [time div 3600, bar count]

How to I combine the output such that:

Output: [Time div 3600, foo count, bar count]

Comment: this selects are not correct

Comment: Don't you also want `time div 3600` in the `SELECT`?  Or maybe `(time div 3600) * 3600`, or even `FROM_UNIXTIME((time div 3600) * 3600)` ??

Answer (score 1):

You can combine them like this:

```
select 
    count(CASE WHEN sub like '%bar%' or comment like '%bar%' THEN postid ELSE NULL END) AS count_bar, 
    count(CASE WHEN sub like '%foo%' or comment like '%foo%' THEN postid ELSE NULL END) AS count_foo
from 
    myTable 
where 
    (sub like '%bar%' or comment like '%bar%'
     or sub like '%foo%' or comment like '%foo%') 
    and replies IS NOT NULL
group 
    by time div 3600 
order by 
    time div 3600 asc;
```

Note that I also change `and replies IS NOT NULL`, assuming you have rows that are actually `NULL`. With the quotes you used, you treated it as a string, but `NULL` is really nothing. You can't compare it like other datatypes, you have to use the special `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` comparison.